# VBA is converting my Sharepoint UNC path to a URL

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a macro that will create a shortcut to the sharepoint folder for each group in a list (and open it in windows explorer). I'm setting the targetpath to the UNC path for the folders, but it keeps converting it to the URL for the folder.

```html
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortCut(Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "Group 5432.lnk")
   .targetpath = "\\company.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\Company\account\Group5432"
   .description = "Sharepoint Folder"
   .save
End With
```

It converts the path to "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Company/account/Group5432"
I can't find any way to prevent it from doing this.

Comment: Note 1: & "Group..." ==> & "\Group...". Note 2: try .targetpath = "file:\\company.sharepoint.com..."

Comment: Still converts to URL :[

Comment: Well... Interestingly... Changing the target type to .URL stops it from converting it to a URL and let's it work...